# Add reference object to the fixed array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add object of type Shoe into the fixed array of type Shoe, but I have a problem with it.

In the addShoe method I am trying to add reference of type Shoe to the sh array like this: sh.add(s);

when I trie to run it I get this error:

Cannot invoke add(Shoe) on the array type Shoe[]
Eclipse recommends me to change it to 'length' and it doesn't make sens

I am also thinking I could write an else part of the addShoes method like this:

```
 
    public void addShoe(Shoe s) throws ShoeException
    {
        if(s.getId() < 0) {
            throw new ShoeException(s);
        }
                else {
                        if(numShoes<=10){
                            sh = Arrays.add(s, numShoes);
                            numShoes++;
                        }
                }
         }
```

It is just one of the ideas. Is it the correct way to do it?

```
 
    public class TestShoe {
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ShoeProcessor s = new Shoe();
    Shoe s1 = new Shoe(7, "Black");
    Shoe s2 = new Shoe(10, "Red");

    try {
        s.addShoe(s1);
                    s.addShoe(s2);

    }catch(ShoeException bex){
        System.out.println("Shoe Exception:  "  + bex);
    }
```

}
    }

```
public class ShoeProcessor
{
private Shoe [] sh;
private int numShoes=0;
private ShoeComparator<Shoe> sc;

public ShoeProcessor()
{
    sh = new Shoe [10];
    sc=new ShoeComparator<Shoe>();
}


public void addShoe(Shoe s) throws ShoeException
{
    if(s.getId() < 0) {
        throw new ShoeException(s);
    }
    else {
        sh.add(s);
        numShoes++;
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for your help

I want to add I need to use array Shoe of fixed size.

I also want to add that I don't want to extend the array sh. I can add max 10 references of type Shoe to it. This is why I am also counting number of shoes added.

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, use `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: +1 @SLaks. Arrays are fixed-size: if you want dynamically extend them you have to either create a new array with size+1, or use an arraylist/vector etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I'm missing something: do you want replace `sh.add(s);` with `sh[numShoes]= s;` ?

Comment: It was exactly my problem. I had hard time to add the reference object of type Shoe to the array of type Shoe. This is why I wrote two different option and everything I have tried. It was simple and I forgot about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java have a fixed size.  You have two options:

- Switch to using a `List`.  This can dynamically grow when you add more items to it.  For implementation you can use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.
- Try using [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to resize your array each time you need to add to it.  I don't recommend this.  Internally, this is actually something that `ArrayList` does, but you are free to do it manually if you so choose.

edit: Just saw your edit. You can do something like:

```
public void addToList(Shoe shoe) {
    if(shoeList.size() < 10) {
        shoeList.add(shoe);
    }
}

shoeArrayCount = 0;
public void addToArray(Shoe shoe) {
    if(shoeArrayCount < 10) {
        shoeArray[shoeArrayCount] = shoe;
        shoeArrayCount++;
    }
}
```

Depending on which method you choose to inplement.